# get attribute values by grouping nodes XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes

I have a large xml file with several nodes `slide` and the below is a part of my large xml.

```
<slide add_info="e" name="slide31.xml" nav_lvl_1="Contact" nav_lvl_2="Company" >
    --------something----------
</slide>
<slide add_info="a" name="slide32.xml" nav_lvl_1="References" nav_lvl_2="Company">
    -----something----
</slide>
<slide add_info="b" name="slide33.xml" nav_lvl_1="References" nav_lvl_2="Company" >
    ------something--------
</slide>
<slide add_info="c" name="slide34.xml" nav_lvl_1="References" nav_lvl_2="Company" >
    --------something----------
</slide>
<slide add_info="d" name="slide34.xml" nav_lvl_1="Contact" nav_lvl_2="Company" >
    --------something----------
</slide>
```

Here i need to group only the `slide` node which has attribute `References` and `Company` and get the all the `add_info` attribute `values` of those nodes.For example 
expected output:

```
a b c
```

Currently I am doing :

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@nav_lvl_1='References'">
        <xsl:if test="@nav_lvl_2='Company'">
        <xsl:for-each select="//@add_info">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
```

But this gives me `all` the text value of `add_info` attribute in the whole document.For example:
it  gives me:

```
e a b c d
```

But I need the output only as `a b c`
How could i change the above `xslt` code to achieve that.. Any sugggestions..I am stuck here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "group" but grouping is particular to wanting to create multiple groups with the same properties.

To select only a single set of constructs with particular properties, simply address them in a single XPath address:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//slide[@nav_lvl_1='References' and @nav_lvl_2='Company'">
   <xsl:value-of select="@add_info"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

... though I would give up on `//slide` and use an address without `//` to get to the parent of all slides and then address the slides as children.